# How to remove a border?

Tags: css, list, html-lists

I have a relatively straight forward question.  I want to edit a specific portion of my list, but I'm not sure how to format the CSS.  Here's the code:

```
<ul class="upcoming">
    <li class="post-265 tribe_events type-tribe_events status-publish hentry">
        <div class="event">
            <a href="http://sacspartans.org/event/big-10-alumni-picnic/">Big 10 Alumni Picnic</a>
        </div>
        <div class="when">
            June 2, 2013 11:00 am – <br>June 2, 2013 3:00 pm 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to modify the li portion of the formula (i.e., to add a border, remove a border, etc.) but I can't figure out how to start the code.

event.li didn't work.  li.event didn't work.  I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I can't figure it out.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldnt it just be `li div.event`

Answer (score 1):

Remove a border is:

```
<li style="border:none;">
```

Or in your CSS styles:

```
li.tribe_events {border: none;}   /* either or*/
li div.event {border: none;}
```

But it's unclear as to whether you want to just do this statically, or want to do that dynamically from JQuery or whatever, in response to something happening.  You probably need to specify what the situation is.

In JQuery:

```
$("li").css("border", "none");
$("#ID_of_some_element").css("border", "none");
```

But it's an issue of *which* `<li>` and *when*, really, isn't it.

If you're talking existing Javascript, `event.target` will give you the target node of DOM events such as hover, onclick  etc.

Comment: I went with Option #1... worked like a champ.  I'm new to this and I often get confused when we start talking about classes under classes under classes with li and ul, etc, etc.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it from the div: `li .event` is what you want. If it's from the list item it's `.upcoming li`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Simples

**Although** I'm sure what you're looking for is far less simple than originally stated

Answer (score 0):

This should most likely work if I understand what you are asking:

```
li div.event {
    border: none;
}
```

(or even more specific)

```
ul.upcoming div.event {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have a hard time keeping all this straigh tin my head.  li ul classes, div, etc. and how to format each level.  Thanks though!

Comment: @jthespartan Its pretty simple once you get to know it, just item.class child.class ..etc as far down as you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

`li.event` selects a `li` element with `event` class. You don't have that.

You have `div` element with `event` class. So, you weren't specific which element you need, but to select your `li` element you need `ul.upcoming li`; and to select your divs inside it: `li div.event` (or `ul.upcoming li div.event` or just `.event`, depending on how specific you need to be).

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="post-265 tribe_events type-tribe_events status-publish hentry">
```

Wow.. you have applied a lot of class name here. Would be better if you just using one or two class name which is specifically for that `ul li`styling, like:

```
.upcoming li{
 /* any styling for the list goes here */
}
```

or maybe just create a new class name just for that list styling

```
.the-list{
    display:block; /*to align it horizontally just use display:inline; */
    (etc...)
}
```

So it looks nicer and easier to maintain it later on right? Happy coding!